# Spyder Launching error: Core File can not be generated

Tags: anaconda, spyder

When I try to launch Spyder IDE through terminal it generates the following error message.

```
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000108
#0 0x7fdeee34652f <unknown>
#1 0x7fdeecd77b1d <unknown>
#2 0x7fdeee346a3e <unknown>
#3 0x7fdf196d4890 <unknown>
#4 0x7fdedfdaa954 <unknown>
#5 0x7fdedfdabbe8 <unknown>
#6 0x7fdf13e5d914 glXCreatePbuffer
#7 0x7fdeecdd9c09 <unknown>
#8 0x7fdeecdc4c68 <unknown>
#9 0x7fdeeee8269d <unknown>
#10 0x7fdeed0c86d1 <unknown>
#11 0x7fdeed0c9ec5 <unknown>
#12 0x7fdeef338a67 <unknown>
#13 0x7fdef0b52605 <unknown>
#14 0x7fdeee3aeee5 <unknown>
#15 0x7fdeee3aa280 <unknown>
#16 0x7fdf196c96db start_thread
#17 0x7fdf193f288f clone
r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 0000000000000001 r10: 0000000000000000 r11: 0000000000000206
r12: 0000559ccf304330 r13: 0000559ccf304330 r14: 0000000000000009 r15: 0000559ccf1c1dc0
di: 0000559ccf193e60  si: 0000000000000000  bp: 0000559ccf193e60  bx: 0000000000000000
dx: 0000000000008041  ax: ffffffffffffff50  cx: 0000000000000000  sp: 00007fde977fd480
ip: 00007fdedfdaa954 efl: 0000000000010202 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000108
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

I have update the navigator and Spyder but it doesn't work. I tried launching from Anaconda. It won't launch and won't even show any error messages.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a problem caused by faulty graphics card drivers. Please try to update them, and if you're on Windows, please update DirectX too.

Comment: I use Spyder on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: Then you need to update your Nvidia drivers or switch to use your Intel card.